# Google site and Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

```
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/view/quizapptest");
Logger.log(site.getName());
```

I run this script. And I got error invalid argument url

Comment: That is a response if the url is giving a 404 not found, or any other error for that matter

Comment: But this url https://sites.google.com/view/quizapptest is not give a 404 for the account scriptstack0@gmail.com. And code is also written in that mail.

Comment: I got an answer. Code will works only classic site not for new Google site

Comment: add that as an answer to your own question - it's helpful information for future googlers.

Comment: Currently the new Google Sites does not provide API access. So if you need API access you are stuck with classic sites.